# Listar keyspaces no Cassandra

Tags: banco-de-dados, linux, nosql, cassandra

Preciso aprender a usar o Apache Cassandra. Estou seguindo um livro chamado Cassandra: o guia definitivo - Jeffrey Carpenter. Consegui fazer a instalação numa boa, pelo que parece, mas quando executo o comando :

```
sudo cassandra -f
```

obtenho como saída:

```
Running Cassandra as root user or group is not recommended - please start Cassandra using a different system user.
If you really want to force running Cassandra as root, use -R command line option.
```

então eu tento iniciar o cassandra sempre privilégio de super user

```
cassandra -f
```

mas recebo um erro dizendo :

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /var/log/cassandra/gc.log due to Permission denied
```

Além disso, tentei criar uma keyspace através do CQL Shell, que aparentemente foi criada com sucesso, mas quando executo o comando:

```
cqlsh> DESCRIBE KEYSPACE
```

obtenho como resposta:

```
Not in any keyspace
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Você não tem nenhum KEYSPACE definido ainda, seu livro provavelmente está desatualizado em relação a versão atual do CQL disponível na sua instalação, procure essa [referência da Datastax](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/index.html) que é a atual mantenedora do Cassandra e do CQL.

Dê uma lida novamente sobre o modelo de dados e veja as operações de query com CQL.

Para criar seu KEYSPACE:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE seukeyspacenome WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 3 };
```

Para usar seu Keyspace:

```
USE seukeyspacenome;
```

Answer (score 0):

@roooooon Obtem-se `Not in any keyspace` na execução deste comando, por causa do erro de sintaxe:

`DESCRIBE KEYSPACE`

> Você se esqueceu do **"s"** e o **";"** no final

A forma correta para Listar keyspaces/cassandra é:

```
 cqlsh> DESCRIBE keyspaces;
```

O resulstado será:

```
 system_schema system system_auth system_distributed system_traces
```

espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Para listar todas as keyspaces no cassandra basta utilizar a seguinte consulta:

`SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;`

Answer (score 0):

[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.6 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.

```
cqlsh> desc keyspaces;
```

Answer (score -1):

Para Listar Keyspaces:

```
DESCRIBE keyspaces;
```

Comment: Na pergunta o autor diz que o comando já resulta em erro *Not in any keyspace*

Comment: Uma vez que a instalação é bem feita, o resultado seria este: cqlsh> Describe keyspaces;

system_schema  system  
system_auth    system_distributed  system_traces

cqlsh>

Comment: Ele cometeu um erro de sintaxe, esscrevendo **DESCRIBE KEYSPACE** que o correto é `DESCRIBE keyspaces;`

Comment: coloque isso na resposta, que foi um erro de sintaxe